# Unity ARPro and VideoPlayer sometimes crash about msmpeg2vdec.dll when playing 8K video

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, video-player

I use AVPro play videos in Unity on Windows. There are two devices, they have same hardware. But in one device, the software may crash about msmpeg2vdec and another is always ok.

```
CPU:I9 13900K 
ASUS  ROG STRIX Z790-A GAMING WIFI
64GB DDR5 6000(32G×2)
Nvdia RTX A5000 24G
```

crash logs

```
0x00007FFFF5BE62A8 (msmpeg2vdec) DllUnregisterServer
0x00007FFFF5BEDE63 (msmpeg2vdec) DllUnregisterServer
0x00007FFFF5BD05D6 (msmpeg2vdec) DllUnregisterServer
0x00007FFFF5BE8F33 (msmpeg2vdec) DllUnregisterServer
0x00007FFFF5AE5D10 (msmpeg2vdec) DllGetClassObject
0x00007FFFF5AE7257 (msmpeg2vdec) DllGetClassObject
0x00007FF839887614 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FF839EE26B1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart
```

I tried change AVPro to VideoPlayer of Unity, it still may crash without error log or crash report.
I checked windows version and hardware driver version, all same.
I also tried recode the videos, the crash still happen.